# Tortoise SVN update slow on the solution node but not on projects nodes

Tags: performance, visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I am having a little problem with tortoise SVN: in Visual Studio 2010, when updating my solution to the latest version (right click on the top solution node), it takes 2 minutes. However, if I select all the projects nodes of my solution and update to the latest version, it is done in a matter of seconds.

What could explain this situation?

Comment: Do you use any SVN plugin? VisualSVN or AnkhSVN maybe?

Comment: I use the latter: AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio 2.1.8420.8 
 * Ankh.Package 2.1.8420.8
 * Subversion 1.6.11 via SharpSvn 1.6011.1539.9366

Answer (score 1):

When you are updating at the solution level it causes an `svn update` on the root directory, probably it contains more directories then are available in your solution in Visual Studio. In other words, some subdirectories of the root directory are not visible in your solution in Visual Studio.

Comment: I understand this. I have to edit my question, it takes a few seconds when I select all the projects and update them. So there is a time difference of two minutes whereas I select all the projects. This is not logical, is it?

Comment: @user2211358 changed my answer to reflect that

Comment: I checked twice, it is not the case. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

when you update the solution, you update from the directory the *.sln file is in. That includes all your bin/obj/tmp/... folders that are not under version control at all but still affect svn.

if you update all projects, then svn updates each folder the *.proj (*.csproj, *.vcproj, ...) is in, and those don't contain the bin/obj/tmp folders. So that update runs a lot faster.

if you want to speed up updating the solution:
add all folders that contain unversioned items to the ignore list (i.e. set the svn:ignore property on the solution folder for those unversioned folders).
That will tell svn that it does not have to check all the files in those folders and updating will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However we did ignore all bin / obj etc. folders a while ago. I just checked if there were unversioned files to commit, it's not the case.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with tortoise svn though, when I update the solution in Windows Explorer, it  is very fast. It's when I use ANkhSVN in Visual Studio that is is painfully slow.